Downloading .csv file with time series of Landsat 8 EVI2 from multiple points using Google Earth Engine
I am trying to download a .csv file with a time series of Landsat 8 EVI2 from multiple points using GEE according to the following code:
var roi = ee.FeatureCollection([
 ee.Feature(ee.Geometry.Point([-43.8115,-16.6648]), {plot_id: 1}),
 ee.Feature(ee.Geometry.Point([-43.7923,-16.663]), {plot_id: 2}),
 ee.Feature(ee.Geometry.Point([-43.7794,-16.6596]), {plot_id: 3}),
 ee.Feature(ee.Geometry.Point([-43.8879,-16.7316]), {plot_id: 4}),
 ee.Feature(ee.Geometry.Point([-43.8487,-16.6756]), {plot_id: 5}),
 ee.Feature(ee.Geometry.Point([-43.8274,-16.6888]), {plot_id: 6}),
 ee.Feature(ee.Geometry.Point([-43.8946,-16.7579]), {plot_id: 7}),
 ee.Feature(ee.Geometry.Point([-48.3,-18.9833]), {plot_id: 8}),
 ee.Feature(ee.Geometry.Point([-44.1224,-16.3708]), {plot_id: 9}),
 ee.Feature(ee.Geometry.Point([-44.1134,-16.3687]), {plot_id: 10})
]);

// Intervalo de tempo da minha série temporal
var startdate = '2013-04-01'; 
var enddate = '2024-04-30'; 

var years = ee.List.sequence(ee.Date(startdate).get('year'), ee.Date(enddate).get('year'));


// This function masks clouds in Landsat 8 imagery.
 function maskL8(im) {
   var qa = im.select('QA_PIXEL');
   var mask = qa.eq(2720);
   return im.updateMask(mask).copyProperties(im);
 }

var ls8toa = ee.ImageCollection('LANDSAT/LC08/C02/T1_L2')
.filterBounds(roi)
  .filterDate(startdate, enddate)
  .filter(ee.Filter.lt('CLOUD_COVER',0.3))
    .map(function(im) {return maskL8(im)});

// Calcula EVI2 a partir do Landsat8

var ls8_evi2 = ls8toa.map(function(image) {
  var evi2 = image.expression(
    '2.5*(NIR-RED)/(NIR+2.4*RED+1)', {
      'NIR': image.select('SR_B5'),
      'RED': image.select('SR_B4')
}).rename('EVI2');
return image.addBands(evi2);
});

var landsat = ee.ImageCollection(ls8_evi2);
var EVI2 = ls8_evi2.select(['EVI2']);
print(EVI2, 'EVI2');
print('Quantas Imagens', EVI2.size());

//Função pra calcular valores médios para cada ponto
var pointsmean = function(image) {
  var means = image.reduceRegions({
    collection: roi.select(['plot_id']),
    reducer: ee.Reducer.mean(),
    scale: 30
  });
  
  // Atribuindo datas
  means = means.map(function(f) { return f.set({date: image.date().format("YYYY-MM-dd")}) });
  
  return means.copyProperties(image);
};

var finalEVI2 = EVI2.map(pointsmean).flatten()
.sort('date', false);

print(finalEVI2, 'final EVI2');

// Exportar tabela em csv direto pro Drive
Export.table.toDrive({
collection: finalEVI2,
  description: 'EVI2_walter_'+startdate+'_TO_'+enddate,
  folder: 'LS8_walter',
fileFormat: 'CSV'
});


The output shown in the console is:

The .csv file is not what I expected (See figure below). I need columns named 'date', 'plot_id', and 'EVI2' with the values.

What is wrong and how do I fix it?

Your code has a couple of issues, particularly with applying the maskL8 function (within map()) and in the cloud cover filter. In the filter, you used 0.3 instead of 30 for cloud cover, which would likely return few or no images.
The code below does not apply cloud masking. To format the final output table, I used a join to group the images by year, calculate the annual mean, and then transform the image collection into a multiband image, where each band corresponds to a year. After that, I applied a reducer to calculate the mean EVI2 for each point in the roi collection. Using a mean reducer in this step doesn't make much difference, as there's no average for a single point).
Here is the script (comments in PT-BR):
https://code.earthengine.google.com/b976010d6fe506dac3d6f927d3ca8ad4

Thank you for your answer, Iago. However, I need one value per image (daily values) for each plot, instead of one value per year.

It wasn't clear from your question that you wanted daily values. Here is the updated script: https://code.earthengine.google.com/3cec791f6c81355499718965d162e879
